# Calling preload method of Angular PreloadingStrategy by hand

Tags: angular, angular-routing

assume, we have 2 modules named(Careworker/Client). In the Client module, we have one module called(Client-Profile). In this way, SelectiveStrategyService does not load modules will only store the name of that module. that's why it can not access the name of (client-profile-module).

In the following service (SelectiveStrategyService ), we will keep track of these routes, but instead of calling the load function immediately, we will store it in a dictionary so we can access it later

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Route, PreloadingStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class SelectiveStrategyService implements PreloadingStrategy {
  routes: { [name: string]: { route: Route; load: Function } } = {};

  preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {

    if (route.data && route.data['preload']) {
      // load();
      this.routes[route.data.name] = {
        route,
        load
      };
    }

    return Observable.of(null);
  }

  preLoadRoute(name: string) {
    const route = this.routes[name];
    if (route) {
      route.load();
    }
  }

}
```

app.routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "careworker", loadChildren: "app/careworker/careworker.module#CareworkerModule",
    data: { preload: false, name: "careworker-module" }
  },
  {
    path: "client", loadChildren: "app/client/client.module#ClientModule",
    data: { preload: true, name: "client-module" }
  }
];
```

client.routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "index", component: ClientIndexComponent
  },
  {
    path: "profile",
    loadChildren: "app/client/client-profile/client-profile.module#ClientProfileModule",
    data: { preload: true, name: "client-profile-module" }
  }
];
```

SelectiveStrategyService are just services, so they can be injected into our components like any other service:

```
constructor(private loader: SelectiveStrategyService) {}
```

**Update :**

in the routes Dictionary, there must be 3 keys (careworker-module,client-module , client-profile-module) , but just there are 2 keys(careworker-module,client-module). that's why I can not call the Client Profile module by hand like:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loader.preLoadRoute('client-profile-module');
}
```

needless to say I can call preLoadRoute ('client-module;) so easily and it works

```
  this.loader.preLoadRoute('client-module');
```

Comment: Manual invocation makes sense for routes that haven't been loaded yet. Could you elaborate more on what exactly you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom preloading strategy of your own. Create a class that implements PreloadingStrategy interface and add your logic there. You can read the `data` object from route do some logic based on that.

```
export class AppPreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
    preload(route: Route, load: Function): Observable<any> {
        const loadRoute = (delay) => delay
            ? timer(150).pipe(flatMap(_ => load()))
            : load();
        return route.data && route.data.preload 
            ? loadRoute(route.data.delay)
            : of(null);
      }
}
```

then use this new strategy in your code like

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { 
   preloadingStrategy: AppPreloadingStrategy
})
```

If a load of module happens there is no point to undo. You can manually invoke the preloading of routes that haven't been loaded yet.

Comment: And if you use SSR make sure to add a check that the active platform is browser.